# Custom content entity field widget. This value should not be null

Tags: 8, entities, plugins

I've created a custom content entity in Drupal 8 and all is well in those regards. I have an issue when I go to create a new record for my entity using the entity form. "**This value should not be null.**".

The error comes from a widget plugin that I've created that only replicates the functionality of a list of checkboxes that represent taxonomy terms. The field that uses this widget is not a base field, it's added through the UI. 
I've looked at the plugin documentation on drupal.org and haven't found much help in regards to my issue.

---

Below, is my code for the widget form element.

```
namespace Drupal\my_entity\Plugin\Field\FieldWidget;

use Drupal\Core\Field\FieldItemListInterface;
use Drupal\Core\Form\FormStateInterface;
use Drupal\Core\Field\Plugin\Field\FieldWidget\OptionsWidgetBase;
use Drupal\Core\Ajax\AjaxResponse;
use Drupal\Core\Ajax\ReplaceCommand;
use Drupal\taxonomy\Entity\Term;
use Drupal\user\Entity\User;

/**
 * A widget for displaying terms and supplying an AJAX request when a checkbox is clicked
 *
 * @FieldWidget(
 *   id = "my_entity_programme_areas_lookup_directors",
 *   module = "my_entity",
 *   label = @Translation("Programme Areas Lookup Directors Widget"),
 *   field_types = {
 *     "entity_reference"
 *   }
 * )
 */
class ProgrammeAreasLookupDirectorsWidget extends OptionsWidgetBase
{

  /**
   * {@inheritdoc}
   */
  public function formElement(FieldItemListInterface $items, $delta, array $element, array &$form, FormStateInterface $form_state) {

    $value = isset($items[$delta]->value) ? $items[$delta]->value : NULL;

    $element = parent::formElement($items, $delta, $element, $form, $form_state);

    $element += [
      '#type'          => 'checkboxes',
      '#default_value' => $this->getSelectedOptions($items),
      '#options'       => $this->getOptions($items->getEntity()),
      '#multiple'      => TRUE,
      '#element_validate' => [
        [static::class, 'validate'],
      ],
      '#prefix' => '<div id="programme-areas-directors-lookup">',
      '#suffix' => '</div>',
    ];

    unset($element['#options']['_none']);
    return ['value' => $element];
  }

  /**
    * @inheritdoc
    */
  public static function validate($element, FormStateInterface $form_state) {

    $value = $element['#value'];
    return true;
  }
```

For the moment, I just want it to pass validation so then I can work on from there, but right now, it can't seem to retrieve a value, even though I can see it has the expected values in the `$form_state` object (field_programme_areas field).

[image]

Any help and tips would be greatly appreciated.
Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I managed to get it working by extending the `OptionsButtonsWidget` class instead of `OptionsWidgetBase`. I've also added the `multiple_values` annotation which I was missing and also removed the validation callback I was supplying, so now the `validateElement` method from `OptionsWidgetBase` is the validation handler used. My widget class just extends `OptionsButtonsWidget` and works fine. I think the missing annotation was the main reason it wouldn't validate.

Comment: Glad you figured out that inheritance is good way to go in D8.

Answer (score 1):

I had exactly the same problem with a custom entity extending Datetime (shamelessly adapted from datetime range: in my case, I need a datetime with a comment). I followed your suggestions, adding `multiple_values` to the annotations of the widget, and extending `DateTimeDefaultWidget` rather than `DateTimeWidgetBase`, but it wasn't enough, I also had to add `setRequired(FALSE)` on the property definitions in FieldType. It seems odd to me, because "required" in such a case should mean "the properties are required if there is an attached entity", yet it apparently means something different, or maybe there is a subtle bug that I don't understand.

Comment: What was the error message you were getting before adding setRequired? Maybe it requires you to explicitly set that for strictness.

Comment: It was the usual **This value should not be null**, with all the fields of my entity set to red. I don't understand, maybe I should set _what_ for strictness?

Comment: As in always setting the setRequired() method for strictness. Maybe field type  definitions get a bit funny when it doesn't know for sure if it's a required field or not and so it doesn't assume a default value.